# Logout from FB application - PHP SDK - problem with URL parameters

Tags: php, facebook, redirect, logout

I'm using in the function `getLogoutUrl()` in order to enable to the user to log out.

When the user is on url page with parameters there is a problem. If the user will press on logout link which directs to `A.php` page which is including header command. The header url is (example):

```
https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http://bla.net?x=100&y=200&z=120
```

it will redirect to:

```
http://bla.net?x=100
```

and not to the full URL.

I've tried to use in `urlencode` on `http://bla.net?x=100&y=200&z=120` but it didn't help. It's redirecting to Facebook home page.

I'd like to get any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's working for me, are you using the `next` parameter? `$facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' => 'http://example.com/example.php?a=1&b=2&c=3'));` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a known bug in the old PHP SDK , as far as I remember. If you have not switched to the new PHP SDK, I would recommend doing that. But as a workaround for your current problem - use the JavaScript SDK to logout ( either thru AJAX or just echoing out the js snippet from your PHP code). Redirect to your desired URL in it's callback function:

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
  window.location="redirect URL";
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I use the new PHP SDK (version 3) so perhaps it was not fixed.